# How to Add html element in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add whole html element to data attribute so that on click I can set it to localstorage and can use it on next pages as well instead of doing the same stuff again on next page ...

Here is what I was doing...

Checking if img_src has a value or not 
if false than set a div with letter X and some styling
if true set img tag with src and some width and height

```
      var img_src="userpic.png"; //this value comes from db
      if(img_src=="" || img_src==null){
        var po_img = '<div class="class-groupPic bg-1">X</div>';
      }
      else{
        var po_img = '<img src="'+element.student.photo+'" width="34" height="34"/>';
      }

      <div class="col" data-img="'+po_img+'" data-religion="Hindu" data-category="OBC"></div>
```

Jquery on click

```
        $(".col").on('click',function(){
           window.localStorage.setItem('img',$(this).data('img'));
           window.localStorage.setItem('religion',$(this).data('religion'));
           window.localStorage.setItem('category',$(this).data('category'));            
        });
```

But this adding html inside data attirbute results
[image]

This above image is my html page result

Comment: Try data-img="'+JSON.stringify(po_img)+'" and then JSON.parse on the next page, but why not just the src?

Comment: Thankyou... Let me try and reply you.. and not just src coz then on next page again i will have to check if src is empty or not again and i was just being lazy of doing that again ;)

Comment: No Bro Still same issue @mplungjan

Comment: https://www.straitstimes.com/opinion/guys-please-stop-saying-bro-dude-and-mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that works is using jQuerys constructor to create the elements and then using those elements to set the `data-` attributes to store it. This example works and seems to do what you want.

```js
var img_src = "userpic.png"; //this value comes from db
var element = {
  student: {
    photo: "myImage.com"
  }
}; // for this example only

var $po_img;
if (img_src == "" || img_src == null) {
  $po_img = $('<div>', { class: "class-groupPic bg-1"});
  $po_img.text("X");
} else {
  $po_img = $('<img/>', {src: element.student.photo, width: 34, height: 34});
}

var $myDiv = $('<div/>', { id: "myDiv", class: "col"});
$myDiv.text("I am the div");
$myDiv.attr("data-img", $po_img[0].outerHTML);
$myDiv.attr("data-religion", "Hindu");
$myDiv.attr("data-category", "OBC");

// add the div to the DOM
document.write($myDiv[0].outerHTML);

// Retrieve the img HTML from the div's data attribute
var theImage = $("#myDiv").attr("data-img");
console.log(theImage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```